# node process reload after after server restart(no npm)

Tags: node.js, centos, rhel

I want to reload/restart node service automatically after server patching/restart. I cant install any npm package on server cause we don't give access to external network so I copy all `node_modules` through winscp. so `npm install -g pm2` will not work not even any type of ***npm install*** will work.

Comment: Copy the offline installer of pm2 in your server and install it